# MongoDB plugin - how to make it to not create a datasource during testing?

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, grails

I'm working on in a project using Grails 2.3.8 and MongoDB. In my project I've included [MongoDB GORM plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) along with hibernate to simplify the DB connection stuff:

#### BuildConfig.groovy

```
// default config stuff here

grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
   ...

   plugins {
       ...
       compile ":mongodb:3.0.3"
       runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.4"
    }
}
```

#### DataSource.groovy

```
environments {

    development {
        grails {
            mongo {
                host = "localhost"
                port = 27017
                databaseName = "myDB"
                // runs without --auth option needs no authentication
            }
        }
    }

    production {
        grails {
            mongo {
                databaseName = "myDB"
                username = "user"
                password = "*****"
                replicaSet = [
                        "master-host:port",
                        "slave1-host:port",
                        "slave2-host:port"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works just fine if I run my app on my local machine (development) or pre-prod servers.

My problem is I've created an integration test for my controller in which the service is mocked and there's no need to establish a database connection at all. When I run the test like this:

```
grails test test-app --debug-fork --stacktrace --verbose -integration
```

The environment is properly set to "test" but I'm getting this exception:

```
Error Fatal error running tests: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManagerPostProcessor.registerAdditionalTransactionManagers(ChainedTransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.transaction.ChainedTransactionManagerPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ChainedTransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:101)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.loader.GrailsProjectLoader$_configureApplication_closure3.doCall(GrailsProjectLoader.groovy:134)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.loader.GrailsProjectLoader$_configureApplication_closure3.doCall(GrailsProjectLoader.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:342)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.loader.GrailsProjectLoader.configureApplication(GrailsProjectLoader.groovy:131)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.phase.IntegrationTestPhaseConfigurer.prepare(IntegrationTestPhaseConfigurer.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.phase.TestPhaseConfigurer$prepare.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callSafe(AbstractCallSite.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$_runAllTests_closure7.doCall(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:311)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3873)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1354)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$149.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:301)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:216)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$runAllTests$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.runInstance(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.run(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.main(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:151)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1829)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:393)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.initializeIndices(MongoDatastore.java:285)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.createMongoTemplate(MongoDatastore.java:276)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.afterPropertiesSet(MongoDatastore.java:221)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean$afterPropertiesSet.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoDatastoreFactoryBean.getObject(MongoDatastoreFactoryBean.groovy:54)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoDatastoreFactoryBean.getObject(MongoDatastoreFactoryBean.groovy)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:87)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:654)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$300(DBTCPConnector.java:39)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:503)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:451)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:409)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.createIndex(DBCollectionImpl.java:339)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:564)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(DBCollection.java:663)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.ensureIndex(DBCollection.java:603)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore$6.doInDB(MongoDatastore.java:341)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:391)
    ... 85 more
```

Based on this portion of the stacktrace:

```
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out while waiting for a server that matches AnyServerSelector{} after 10000 ms
```

It seems to me the plugin is trying to connect to a mongo instance regardless the environment is "test". It makes sense because if I start a local mongo in my computer the test runs successfuly.

I've spent a day and a half googling for this issue but the common reply is "your mongo instance isn't running". I realised that but for the test I actually don't need it.

For a little more context, this test must run in a Jenkins server which doesn't have any mongo instance running and throws the very same exception as expected.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration tests run against a "fully baked" grails application -- if you use a database in dev and prod, then you'll need one in test.

Besides, if you're really doing the automated testing part, you'll need a test database for other tests, so just create one now. Even if this test doesn't use it, it constitutes part of the "complete grails environment" you are testing.

In your Jenkins job, you can pass an environment setting to direct the test environment to use a specified configuration file for the data source. I do this with a test-specific app-config.groovy file stored down in test/conf/app-config.groovy. That config points to a long-standing AWS RDS instance the Jenkins server can see (the DB isn't on the Jenkins server). The Jenkins build step essentially invokes:

grails test-app -Dapp.config.location=test/conf/app-config.groovy integration:

(I'm facing the same issue at work, just created MySQL DBs for all three environments, dev, prod, and test. And get to do more, since we run with clients choosing between H2, MSSQL, Oracle, or MySQL).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So I was conceptually mistaken. We just talked to architecture team and they gave us permission to install a MongoDB plugin on Jenkins which starts a mongo instance right before running the job and stops it after the job is done. Now we can fully test the app in an appropriate environment.